# Finding the correct noteOff event in a midi file in java

Tags: java, midi

I am programming a tool in Java that does some batch process on midis which include creating tracks and moving notes from one tracks to another.
However, I cant find a reliable way to find the associated Noteoff event of a particular NoteOn. I've seen some post saying to search for the next NoteOff ( or a NoteOn with Velocity = 0 ) on the same pitch, but this assume there are no overlapping notes. If there are overlapping notes, there can be multiple noteOff on the same pitch before the correct one.
Is there a way to reliably find the NoteOff Event of a NoteOn?
https://www.mediafire.com/view/6c4wg0i7extifyw/StackoverFlowMidi.png/file

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note Midi events in raw Midi files only carry **pitch**, **velocity** and **channel** information. So in case of overlapping notes there is no way to know for sure that this Note OFF corresponds to this Note ON.

Furthermore Midi specification does not specify how to react to multiple Note ONs for a same pitch/channel. That's why depending on the used Midi device (a hardware synth, a VST plugin, a Midi player, etc.) you might hear different results.

However an algorithm may choose how to deal with unexpected note events in a consistent way. There are 3 possibilites.

Let's assume your Midi file contains 2 overlapping C notes (same pitch, same channel). Then you will always have the following Midi events sequence: `C_ON(tick1), C_ON(tick2), C_OFF(tick3), C_OFF(tick4)`, where `tick1 <= tick2 <= tick3 <= tick4`.

Some programs consider that notes overlapping is an error so they just ignore the redundant/unexpected Note events. Here it means C_ON(tick2) and C_OFF(tick4) are ignored. You end up with one note C(tick1-tick3).

Other programs use a list (FIFO) to store the Note ONs for the same pitch/channel. Notes are actually created when parsing a Note OFF in the order of the Note ONs. So you end up with 2 notes C(tick1-tick3) and C(tick2-tick4)

Last possibility, use a stack (LIFO) to push each Note ON for the same pitch/channel, and pop it when parsing a Note OFF. In this case you'll end with the 2 notes C(tick1-tick4) and C(tick2-tick3).

*Note that when you save a DAW project with Midi tracks using the DAW file format, DAW can store additional information to manage the overlapping correctly.*

Comment: The midi files I'm working with have notes on the same pitch and channel, so i cant use these to identify the NoteOff.

Comment: Where do these Midi files come from ? They seem VERY unusual. If this is music, you normally always have, for a given channel and pitch, a suite of NoteOn/NoteOff/NoteOn/NoteOff/.... It's logicial: a piano player can't press again a note if it's already pressed.   If you have several successive NoteONs on a given pitch/channel, Midi Specs say it's up to the receiver/player to decide what to do (e.g. ignore it or retrigger note). In this case you would have no way to find which noteOFF is for which noteON, because Midi is not designed to be used like this.

Comment: That was one of the intended feature of my tool, to be able to fix the oddities of those unusual midi found anywhere on net. But there must be a way to know for sure which NoteOff goes with which NoteOn even with overlapping notes, cause all the DAW software always shows the notes the same way.

Comment: They show the notes the same way because most software ignore the redundant NoteONs or NoteOFF. You seem to assume that there is always the same number of NoteON/NoteOFFs. It's rarely the case when a Midi file contains "errors", you often have 2 NoteON for 1 NoteOFF, or the opposite. So you just ignore the 2nd redundant note.

Comment: In the files im testing, there are no redundant NoteOn or NoteOff. Every NoteOn has a NoteOff somewhere. What i mean by they show up the same in the every software: If i create a midi file with overlapping notes and ambiguous (to me) NoteOff, they will still show it exactly how i created it, no matter the configuration.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding on "redundant". I updated the answer to be more clear.